# Continuous TFS local deployment

Tags: tfs, continuous-deployment, post-build-event

I have a configured CI with TFS.  What are the best ways to organize post-build (or even better post-test) deployment. My binaries are some libraries with single executable file.

Here is what I need:

1. Build on each commit. (This is configured and done)
2. When build is successful (or tests), grep binaries and drop it to some specific folder on the same build machine with full replacement of previous files and folders. (I`d like to be able to configure somehow the folder location)
3. Launch the application with some parameters and I need to have standart output redirection. For example: `App.exe param=paramValue > log.txt`
4. And before starting the application I need to kill the previous instance of it. (This is some kind of server instance that is alive all the time)

The most obvious solution that I tried was to do this with post-build script. But this try failed. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985703/tfs-post-build-step-running-application-hangs)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx) in conjunction with PowerShell (or better still, Desired State Configuration) scripts. Depending on your MSDN licensing, it could be free for you, and it's specifically designed from the ground up to handle managing releases.

Overextending the build process to also do deployment is an awful idea. The build tools were designed to build, and they're good at it! They're not good at the types of considerations you have when you're trying to do deployments.

The problem is that most CI solutions (TFS included) would get you to the point where you had binaries, then say "Welp, you're on your own! Have fun figuring out how to deploy this stuff!" This never ends well -- you end up with something inflexible and very difficult to troubleshoot and maintain.

The modern "devops" approach here is to have your application's requirements in source control, treated as code (in this case, as a DSC script or scripts).

One other consideration: It sounds like you're trying to treat a console application as a service. This is going to be a big, big pain for you, since most software that handles releases will not run in an interactive session. Turn it into a true Windows service and your life will be easier.